# mvc output cache with display modes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a mvc4 web site with nuget package Install-Package jQuery.Mobile.MVC
the code for home is :

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "SiteCache", VaryByParam = "none")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I see a problem where sometimes I go from desktop browser and get a layout of mobile.
could it be that a user entered from mobile and the IIS cached for the mobile page and it getting served for users after it as mobile layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is that someone with mobile accessed the site before you. It caches the Action/View in IIS for everybody else. It's server cache, not client.
You could use a Guid param, and cache for it, for the client session to cache the index for every client connected.

Comment: can I do like varybyparam varyby if mobile or not ?

Comment: If the client is mobile or not it's in the Request object. You could use two different action and cache it.